# AES encryption constant input and output size

Tags: string, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a key for AES encryption and I'm trying to encrypt strings with constant length as well, does the resultant encrypted string will always have the same length?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of data after AES/CBC and AES/ECB encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283787/size-of-data-after-aes-cbc-and-aes-ecb-encryption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by 'the same length'.

The same length as the original string: generally no; the original string will be padded to a multiple of the cipher block-length. Check padding modes for details.

The same length every time you encrypt: yes; as long as you stick to the same mode and padding the encrypted output will have the same length.

Comment: By length I ment the count of characters of string after encryption. Provider key and text to encrypt are with constant number of characters, mode is the same as well.

Comment: Then you should expect the encrypted values to have the size of the original strings rounded up to the nearest multiple of 8.
Small caveat: encryption works with BYTES - not characters; so you should expect the number of BYTES to be the nearest multiple of 8. If you use multi-byte characters be aware of this.

Comment: *...nearest multiple of 8...* It's AES, so nearest multiple of **16**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a block cipher requires a full block to encrypt, therefore AES requires 16-byte ( or 128-bit ) input to encrypt will output 16-byte ciphertext. This is always the case for block ciphers since they are Pseudo-Random Permutations (PRP) - they are always permutations we expect them to be PRP.

Block ciphers, like AES, are primitives and must be used with a [proper mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Here we will talk only about some of them.

- **ECB mode** is the default and insecure.

  **Padding:** In the case of the message size is not a multiple of the 128, we apply padding. There are various paddings, however, the most common one is the PCKS#7 ( update of PCKS#5 that was for 64-bit block ciphers like DES). This padding append characters to the end so that the size is multiple of 128.

  Therefore; the appended number of characters for ECB mode can be from 1 to 16 ( if the block size is already a multiple of 128) then a new block is added with 16 `10` bytes.
- **CBC mode** requires a random and unpredictable IV so that we can achieve probabilistic encryption. As in ECB, it requires padding.

  Therefore; the appended number of characters for CBC mode can be from 1+16 to 32 since we need to add the IV to the ciphertext.
- **CTR mode** requires Initial Value (IV) that can be random or deterministic. CTR mode converts a block cipher (PRP) into a stream cipher. The plaintext is x-ored with the ciphertext where the input was the IV and incremented for each encryption. There is no need for padding in CTR mode.

  Therefore; the appended number of characters for CTR mode is (at most)16.
- **AAED**: The above are archaic mode of operations and today we use Authenticated Encryption (with Associated Data) (AE/AEAD). Unlike the archaic modes, these modes can provide us not only confidentiality but also integrity and authentication.

  The authentication part requires a **tag** (MAC tag) and this really depends on the scheme.

  - AES-GCM is the NIST-approved mode. AES-GCM's recommended IV size 12 since different size requires an additional process. It always produces a 16-byte tag, however, one can reduce the size of the tag if they want to, although not recommended.

    At first one might consider that the size is incremented by 12-16, however, it is not. The GCM always used Associated Data (AD) and allows `zeroAD` and the size of the AD is always added. For details, see [NIST GCM specification](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38d/final)

This was the short story of the long list of how the [mode of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) behaves in terms of input vs output length.

If you omit the IV size, it is possible with CTR mode.