# How to use GCrypt AES128 in Vala?

Tags: vala, gcrypt

I tried with this code but the result is not as expected, maybe I am wrong somewhere, please help.

gcrypt.vapi from: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala-extra-vapis

```
using GCrypt;
using Posix;

void main () {
    GCrypt.Cipher.Cipher cipher;
    GCrypt.Error err = GCrypt.Cipher.Cipher.open(out cipher, Cipher.Algorithm.AES128, Cipher.Mode.CBC, Cipher.Flag.SECURE);
    if (err != 0) {
        print("Error: %s\n", err.to_string());
        Process.exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    string iv = "1111111111111111";
    string key = "2222222222222222";
    err = cipher.set_key(key.data);
    if (err != 0) {
        print("Error key: %s\n", err.to_string());
        Process.exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    err = cipher.set_iv(iv.data);
    if (err != 0) {
        print("Error iv: %s\n", err.to_string());
        Process.exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    string str = "Hello World!!!!!";
    uchar[] ary = new uchar[str.length];
    print("ary: %d\n", ary.length);
    err = cipher.encrypt(ary, str.data);
    if (err != 0) {
        print("Error encrypt: %s\n", err.to_string());
        Process.exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    string result = Base64.encode(ary);
    print("ary: %d\n", ary.length);
    print("result: %s\n", result); // tus0150r+OSFg63kxluXpg==
    // expect result: tus0150r+OSFg63kxluXpmlrUQOsLMbbgx51GhLZats=

    cipher.close();
    Process.exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output buffer `ary` is sized too small so you're losing data. <strike>You can't assume that the encrypted output will be the same size as the input data:</strike>

```
uchar[] ary = new uchar[str.length]
```

*Edit: I was incorrect, since AES is a block cipher the size will be the same, however the padding scheme must be considered*

Here's an example of creating an output buffer of the correct size (granted it's for AES256, not AES128, so you'll need to make some adjustment): https://github.com/JCWasmx86/LFinance/blob/e6057b38a594ecbef728b212d9aa7df8cd8e869b/src/crypto/encryption.vala

That code has a link out to another Stack Overflow post about determining the correct size: [Size of data after AES/CBC and AES/ECB encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283787/size-of-data-after-aes-cbc-and-aes-ecb-encryption/3284136#3284136)

Unfortunately I don't know enough about AES to provide the exact size that you'll need, but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction!

Comment: Hehe, this is my code :), but it works, but I'm not sure whether it is correct